# Android MapView is not working

Tags: android

Logcat output:

```
[2010-01-09 15:47:19 - HelloMapView]------------------------------
[2010-01-09 15:47:19 - HelloMapView]Android Launch!
[2010-01-09 15:47:19 - HelloMapView]adb is running normally.
[2010-01-09 15:47:19 - HelloMapView]Performing org.example.hellomapview.HelloMapView activity launch
[2010-01-09 15:47:19 - HelloMapView]Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.
[2010-01-09 15:47:21 - HelloMapView]Performing org.example.hellomapview.HelloMapView activity launch
[2010-01-09 15:47:22 - HelloMapView]Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2010-01-09 15:47:22 - HelloMapView]Starting activity org.example.hellomapview.HelloMapView on device 
[2010-01-09 15:47:23 - HelloMapView]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2010-01-09 15:47:23 - HelloMapView]ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
[2010-01-09 15:47:23 - HelloMapView]ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { comp={org.example.hellomapview/org.example.hellomapview.HelloMapView} }
```

When I run my application it is showing the above error. I am not able to run myMap application I used the same code what they have given in myMap application. Please help me.

Comment: aswanistack: You should edit your question to make the log output more readable. Select the logs and press Ctrl+K (or the little 01010 icon above the text area) to turn it into a formatted snippet.

Comment: Aswan, you should go through your questions and mark answers as accepted (if appropriate). Otherwise people may stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log message `Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'` says it all.

You need to [create an emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html#creating) that includes the Google APIs (and therefore the Google Maps library).

There's a GUI that lets you manage and create new emulator images; just run `android` from your SDK tools folder.